# Test complete. Run test from a specific point

Tags: testcomplete

Does anybody know if it's possible in Test Complete to run a test from a specific point in a function?
I see options like run routine, run test, run project.

Thank you,
Raluca

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to start execution of a script test from a specific line, but it is possible to move the execution point to the desired line. You can set a breakpoint to the first line of a script routine and run this routine. Once the test execution is stopped at the breakpoint, use the **Set Next Statement** action to move the execution point to the needed line and continue the execution.

This feature is documented in the [Setting Next Execution Point](http://support.smartbear.com/support/viewarticle/11358/) help topic.

Answer (score 2):

TestComplete's Keyword Driven Tests have the possibility to add "Labels" and "Go To Labels". 
You can put a label anywhere in your KDT script and set a GoToLabel at the very beginning of your test to move to that point.

It may even be possible to combine this with Project Variables to get a "Last Reached Milestone/Label". This is only speculation, but worth looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

no there is no way you can run testcomplete scripts from a specific point. the closest point you can get to for runnning you script from a specific point is to use break point and then press F10 for executing one by one line of code